# How to use since_id and max_id in tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to pull tweets using since_id and max_id. The problem with since_id is that it correctly prints all the tweets in my eclipse console but when I try to store it line by line as csv file it does not return me all the tweets. I tried running it 4-5 times but every time I get different number of tweets.The problem with max_id is that it is not running. My code is as follows and the traceback is included after the code (For since_id I am just replacing max_id with since_id only)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tweepy
import csv 
from datetime import *
import time
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
#data = api.get_user('abhi1868sharma')#'mishra1_P_K'

csvFile = open('a.csv','a')

csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')#, tweet.favourited
i = 1
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id = '', max_id = 510064587115225000).items()
while True:
    try:
        for tweet in tweets:
            csvWriter.writerow([i, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count, str(tweet.id), tweet.created_at.hour,tweet.created_at.minute,tweet.created_at.weekday(),tweet.created_at.day,tweet.created_at.month,tweet.created_at.year,tweet.created_at ,tweet.text.encode('utf8'), tweet.user.id, tweet.geo, tweet.in_reply_to_user_id, tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str, tweet.place, tweet.retweeted, tweet.truncated, tweet.source])
            print i
            i+=1


    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60 * 15) 
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        break

csvFile.close()
```

This is my traceback for the max_id (for since_id it is not throwing any error)

```
for tweet in tweets:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 181, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 99, in next
    data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kargs)
TypeError: _call() got multiple values for keyword argument 'max_id'
```

One more thing as I am storing the file in csv file my tweet_ids get rounded off. Is there any way to get around it. And the tweet_id that I am using for since_id and max_id are also rounded out tweet ids.

Comment: try using limited range by pass a number in ```item()``` like ```Curser(...).items(10)```